# Why do motorola android devices install >60 background processes and services, and how can they be removed?

Tags: android, memory-management, motorola

Folks,

We are debugging unexplained crashes of our Android app on motorola devices. We have an unhandled exception handler that catches crashes and uploads them to our server, but our users weren't generating these logs, meaning that the OS itself was choosing to kill our app. We typically test on motorola devices that aren't activated with cell service.

As a result of user complaints, we incorporated a task manager to see what other applications were running concurrently. On our development devices we would see between 6-10 applications and services that were not android-specific (ie, all com.google or com.android processes were filtered out).

On one customer device that was experiencing problems, we got the following list:

```
[Process] android.tts: 577 kb / 2221 kb
[Process] com.appspot.scruffapp: 8384 kb / 15683 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.providers.contacts: 4306 kb / 1466 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.service.blur: 1831 kb / 3515 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.service.main: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.contacts.data: 914 kb / 1041 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.home.message: 1205 kb / 1813 kb
[Process] com.motorola.process.system: 911 kb / 911 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.alarmclock: 783 kb / 791 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.home: 5747 kb / 5004 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.conversations: 3054 kb / 4026 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.weather: 1124 kb / 1408 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.home.newsstatus: 2529 kb / 2031 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.socialmessaging: 776 kb / 927 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.contacts: 943 kb / 1069 kb
[Process] com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol: 810 kb / 1204 kb
[Process] com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail: 2394 kb / 2777 kb
[Process] com.fusionone.android.sync.service: 870 kb / 809 kb
[Process] com.motorola.vvm: 803 kb / 918 kb
[Process] com.wsandroid: 937 kb / 1271 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.messaging: 1404 kb / 1476 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.email: 1635 kb / 2258 kb
[Process] com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller: 3280 kb / 5080 kb
[Process] com.motorola.photowidget: 1210 kb / 1014 kb
[Process] com.motorola.togglewidgets: 672 kb / 732 kb
[Process] com.davidgoemans.simpleClockWidget: 930 kb / 1179 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.buacontactadapter: 551 kb / 636 kb
[Process] com.motorola.vclipboard: 593 kb / 626 kb
[Process] com.groupon: 997 kb / 1352 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.home.other: 1262 kb / 890 kb
[Process] com.motorola.cmas: 654 kb / 630 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.datamanager: 1247 kb / 939 kb
[Process] com.motorola.videoplayer: 656 kb / 631 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.syncml.service: 786 kb / 684 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.dm.service: 569 kb / 574 kb
[Process] com.motorola.usb: 655 kb / 757 kb
[Process] com.motorola.batterymanager:deviceStats: 573 kb / 595 kb
[Process] com.motorola.batterymanager: 594 kb / 599 kb
[Process] com.motorola.blur.datamanager.app: 614 kb / 582 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.provisioning: 593 kb / 692 kb
[Process] com.motorola.android.AudioEffectSettings: 552 kb / 595 kb
[Process] com.motorola.globalunplug: 574 kb / 569 kb
[Process] com.swype.android.inputmethod: 558 kb / 585 kb
[Process] com.wsandroid.uninstall_listener: 570 kb / 636 kb
[Process] com.svox.pico: 535 kb / 547 kb
[Process] com.motorola.atcmd: 507 kb / 495 kb
[Process] com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp: 556 kb / 634 kb
[Service] com.motorola.photowidget/.PhotoWidgetAppProvider$WidgetService: 1210 kb / 1014 kb
[Service] com.motorola.usb/.UsbService: 655 kb / 757 kb
[Service] com.fusionone.android.sync.service/.SyncService: 870 kb / 809 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.snmessaging.engine/.SNMessagingService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.news/.widget.NewsWidgetProvider$WidgetService: 2529 kb / 2031 kb
[Service] android/com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper: 6341 kb / 22102 kb
[Service] com.motorola.android.buacontactadapter/.AuthenticationService: 551 kb / 636 kb
[Service] com.motorola.togglewidgets/.GpsToggle$UpdateService: 672 kb / 732 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.richtext/.service.RichClipboardService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.appspot.scruffapp/.C2DMReceiver: 8384 kb / 15687 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.email/.provider.activesync.ActiveSyncEmailService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.weather/.service.WeatherService: 1124 kb / 1408 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.blur/.BlurServiceMother: 1831 kb / 3515 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.weather/.WeatherWidgetProvider$WidgetService: 1124 kb / 1408 kb
[Service] com.motorola.photowidget/.WidgetAidService: 1210 kb / 1014 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.contacts/.CacheService: 943 kb / 1069 kb
[Service] com.motorola.android.syncml.service/.SyncEngineService: 786 kb / 684 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.home.status/.StatusWidgetProvider$WidgetService: 2529 kb / 2031 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.email/.engine.EmailEngine: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.android.datamanager/.DataManagerService: 1247 kb / 939 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.policymgr.service/.PolicyMgrService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.email/.provider.activesync.ActiveSyncPushService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail/.provider.MailSyncService: 2394 kb / 2777 kb
[Service] com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail/com.yahoo.mobile.client.share.push.HTTPKeepAliveService: 2394 kb / 2777 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.blur/.syncstatus.SyncStatusService: 1831 kb / 3515 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.quickcontact/.QuickContactService: 1262 kb / 890 kb
[Service] com.motorola.globalunplug/.service.GlobalUnplugService: 574 kb / 569 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.storagemon/.StorageMonitorService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.service.blur/.sync.ws.impl.BlurSyncWSClient2: 1831 kb / 3515 kb
[Service] com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol/.core.CallControlService: 810 kb / 1204 kb
[Service] com.davidgoemans.simpleClockWidget/.SimpleClockUpdateService: 934 kb / 1179 kb
[Service] android.tts/.TtsService: 577 kb / 2221 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.news/.NewsRetrievalService: 2529 kb / 2031 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.home.message/.MessageWidgetProvider$WidgetService: 1205 kb / 1813 kb
[Service] com.motorola.blur.adminfeed/.AdminFeedNotifierService: 7047 kb / 5563 kb
[Service] com.motorola.android.extdispservice/.ExtDispService: 911 kb / 911 kb
```

This list was retrieved by calling the following code:

```
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningApps = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    List<RunningServiceInfo> runningServices = activityManager.getRunningServices(100);
```

There are 83 processes and services listed, showing native PSS and other PSS. Our app downloads, displays and caches images from the internet, and is the second one listed. We have higher usage than most other apps, but the OS should be able to multitask and page our memory accordingly.

Other than our app, more than 60 of those begin with com.motorola. Can anyone explain if all these processes are needed and if/how users can remove some of these? Device memory exhaustion is the best explanation we can come up with for these unexplained application crashes that are not the result of unhandled exceptions.

Comment: could you provide the name of the device and which android version is running?

Answer (score 1):

Most processes seem to be related to the Motorola modified framework (blur). Others look like running apps, most probably Widgets in the home screen. 
There's no way for your app to change that. If you can contact the user, ask to stop some of the running apps and remove some home Widgets.

Re-reading the list, the fist suspect would be: com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller. See the app description [here](http://www.appbrain.com/app/advanced-task-killer/com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller). Perhaps is using the auto kill feature? Try asking to add your app in the exclusion list.